# Is it possible to update one property for all objects in realm swiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, realm

I want to update one property "complete", but for all objects in realm at the touch of a button.

How can I do that?

My model:

```
class HotelPoint: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {

@Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: ObjectId
@Persisted var nameHotel: String = ""
@Persisted var adresHotel: String = ""
@Persisted var descriptionHotel: String = ""
@Persisted var codeArky: String = ""
@Persisted var codeParadny: String = ""
@Persisted var locker: String = ""
@Persisted var selected = false
@Persisted var complete = false
@Persisted var count: String = "" }
```

I want to update this property in the structure:

```
struct DWork: View {

@State private var hFDWIsPresented = false

@ObservedResults(HotelPoint.self, where: {$0.inWork == true}) var hotelsInWork
@ObservedResults(HotelPoint.self, where: {$0.complete == true}) var hotelsEnded

@ViewBuilder var openHotelForDW: some View {
  Button(action: openHFDW) {
    Label("Добавь Отели", systemImage: "plus.circle.fill")
  }
  .foregroundColor(.green)
  .sheet(isPresented: $hFDWIsPresented) {
      HotelsForDayWork(complete: $complete)
  }
}


@Binding var inProcces: Int
@Binding var complite: Int
@Binding var dWork: Bool


var body: some View {

        HStack {
            List{
                Section("В работе") {
                    if hotelsInWork.isEmpty{
                        openHotelForDW
                    }
                    ForEach(hotelsInWork){name in NameForDay(hotelPoint: name, inProcces: $inProcces, complete: $complete)
                            
                    }
                }
                Section("Выполнено") {
                    if hotelsEnded.isEmpty{
                        Text("Доставь завтраки")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                    ForEach(hotelsEnded){name in NameForDay(hotelPoint: name, inProcces: $inProcces, complete: $complete)
                            
                    }
                }

            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .frame(width: dWork ? 260 : 200, height: dWork ? 560 : 55)
            

            Text ("\(inProcces) из \(complete)")
                .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .semibold))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 55)
                .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(
                        .linearGradient(.init(colors: [Color.blue.opacity(0.7),
                             Color.purple.opacity(0.7),
                            .clear,
                            Color.blue]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing),
                        lineWidth: 2.5
                    )
                    .padding(2)
                )
                .shadow(color: .red.opacity(0.3), radius: 5, x: -5, y: -5)
                .shadow(color: .red.opacity(0.3), radius: 5, x: 5, y: 5)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .offset(x: 0, y: dWork ?  -255 : 0)
                
       }

   }

}
```

The "Выполнено" button itself is located in the main structure of MainView:

```
struct MainView: View {

init() {
//        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
//        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
//        UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    
   }

@ObservedResults(HotelPoint.self) var hotelPoint
@ObservedRealmObject var hotelPointComplete = HotelPoint()


@State var searchText = ""

@State var showCard = false
@State var changeHotelDesc = false
@State var back = CGSize.zero

@State var dayWork = false
@State var dWButtonName = ["Посмотреть", "Назад"]

@State var inProcces = 0
@State var complete = 0

//    let localRealm = try! Realm()
@Environment(\.realm) var localRealm

let layout = [
GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100)),
GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100))
]

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
       
       //MARK: - Background
        Background()
       
        ZStack {
            
            //MARK: - Person
            ...
                
        VStack{
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    
                    //MARK: - Background for Hotels
                    ...
                    //MARK: - Hotels
                    ...
                    
                    //MARK: - Map
                    ...
            
            ZStack {
                //MARK: - Background for DWork
                    ...
                
                //MARK: - DWork
                NavigationView {
                    DWork(inProcces: $inProcces, complete: $complete, dWork: $dayWork)
                        .frame(width: dayWork ? 400 : 340, height: dayWork ? 640 : 140)
//                        .background(Color.green)
                        .navigationBarTitle("Маршрут")
                        .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("\(dayWork ? dWButtonName[1] : dWButtonName[0])") {
                            self.dayWork.toggle()
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black))
                        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Выполнено") {
                            inProcces = 0
                            complete = 0
  //Here I want to place an action that will switch the "complete" property
                            self.dayWork.toggle()
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black))
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                    
                }// end NavigationView for DWork
                .frame(width: dayWork ? 400 : 340, height: dayWork ? 640 : 140)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .offset(x: 0, y: dayWork ? -50 : -280)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.3), value: dayWork)
                .blendMode(.darken)
                
            } //end ZStack for DWork
            .offset(x: 0, y: -295)
           
            } //end VStack
        } //end second ZStack
            .blur(radius: showCard ? 20 : 0)
        
        
//            Text ("\(back.height)").offset(y: -300)

        } //end ferst ZStack
    
    } //end body

} //end MainView
```

How can I assign an action to the "Выполнено" button from the MainView structure, which will affect and accordingly switch the "complete" property in the DWork structure. This is necessary for the items in the "Выполнено" list to disappear upon shutdown.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Yes, you can do a variety of tasks, including updating properties "at the touch of a button". The way SO works is you post the code you've attempted and your troubleshooting along with a description of the issue you're having and then we take a look and help with your existing code. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I changed and edited my question. Is this description enough to answer it?

Comment: It's still unclear - the question title asks about *update one property for all objects in realm* which is definitely a Realm question but the content of the question asks about *assigning a button action* which is an unrelated SwiftUI question. It's also not clear why changing a property is required for a list to disappear - when you say the `Выполнено` list, are you actually referring to the `hotelsEnded` results? If so, those Results are queried for 'true' so you want to change them ALL to false to remove them from Results?

Comment: That's right, I want the results hotelsEnded to change to false

Answer (score 0):

There may be more to the question but let me address the title of the question

> Is it possible to update one property for all objects in realm
> swiftUI?

Yes, it's easy to set the property on all Realm objects to the same value.

Looking at the code, it appears the results var contains all of the HotelPoint objects where `completed` is true. If ALL of those object `completed` are set to false then the results will contain no objects.

Keep in mind this is not the best way to clear results but there may be more to it.

Here's the code - three lines using iteration. You can set other properties at the same time:

```
let hotelResults = realm.objects(HotelPoint.self)

try! realm.write {
    hotelResults.forEach { $0.complete = false}
}
```

optionally, if you only need to set the single field this works but keep in mind Realm is leaning toward more type-safe function calls per the above.

```
let hotelResults = realm.objects(HotelPoint.self)

try! realm.write {
    hotelResults.setValue(false, forKey: "complete")
}
```

So that takes care of *ALL* objects as asked in the question. Alternately, you may want to just update the objects currently in results. Since they are Observed, they can be modified directly and their `complete` values set to false.

Per the docs

> Writes to an ObservedResults collection implicitly perform a write
> transaction.

Which will cause each object set to false to 'fall out' off the results since they no longer match the query criteria.

Comment: Such a record creates an error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'Results<HotelPoint>'

Comment: The following helped me: 
`let realm = try! Realm()
                                let hotelsComplete = realm.objects(HotelPoint.self).where{$0.complete == true}
                                

                                try! realm.write {
                                    hotelsComplete.setValue(false, forKey: "complete")
                                }
`

Comment: @АртемВоробьев My apologies. I was typing and left off the `.forEach` function call. Whoops! The iteration in the answer is handy if you want to set multiple fields. I also include the optional single line, no iteration solution as well. Glad my answer was able to point you in the correct direction.